# Get Telerik Grid columns Header Text

Tags: gridview, web, telerik, telerik-grid

I need to rename my grid headertext. My grid generate using autogenerated columns.i am getting data in Datatable and assigning it to grid. after assigning to grid i am using a function which called after databind() and it format the grid cells but not HeaderText.

Can anybody help me out for this problem?

```
 foreach (GridColumn column in grdTestCertificate.Columns)
        {
            string[] strColumn = column.HeaderText.Split('|');
            column.HeaderText = strColumn[1];
        }
```

it return 0 counts of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aah i got the solutions,

```
 foreach (GridColumn column in grdTestCertificate.MasterTableView.RenderColumns)
        {

             column.HeaderText = "";
        }
     grdTestCertificate.rebind();
```

Point up my answer if you got your solution.